# Deletion of entire entity graph, including relationships, using EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have classes that are structured like the following:

```
public class Forecast
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Stop")]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public virtual Stop Stop { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Direction> Directions { get; set; }
}

public class Direction
{
    public int DirectionId { get; set;}
    public string Abbreviation { get; set;}
    public virtual Forecast Forecast { get; set;}
    public virtual List<Transport> Transports { get; set;}
}

public class Transport
{
    public int TransportId { get; set; }
    public int DirectionId { get; set;}
    public virtual Direction Direction { get; set;}
}

public partial class Stop
{
    [Key]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public virtual Forecast Forecast { get; set; }
}
```

I developed these classes and used EF Code First 4.1 to generate the database.  CF does appear to properly create all of the primary and foreign key relationships between the classes within the database (MSSQL).

My problem is when I want to delete a Forecast. I thought I do could something like the following:

```
        using (MyContext ctxt = new MyContext())
        {
            // get a forecast, somehow, not really important
            // The one assumption is I'm absolutely sure it's 
            // Abbreviation key already exists in the database
            // and the list of Forecasts.
            Forecast f;

            ctxt.Forecasts.Remove(f);
        }
```

This deletes the top-level object from the database just fine.  However, all of its child objects - all of the directions and transports - remain in the database and become orphaned (their key relationship column gets set to null. I expect that but I DON'T know why they're not just deleted).  I have resorted to recursing down the object graph and calling Remove on every object from its appropriate DbSet in ctxt, but that seems like... the wrong way to do it.

What am I missing here?

Why can't I just say

ctxt.Forecasts.Remove(f);

and be done with it?

Edit:

> @Ladislav gave me the right answer - I
>   needed to add [Required] to the
>   Abbreviation property on Direction.
>
> However, I am still forced to actually
>   load the child entities for this to
>   work - doing something as simple as
>
> Direction d = f.Directions[0];
>
> will cause the delete to actually
>   delete the child entities.  I'm well
>   aware that this is due to lazy
>   loading.  I thought the point of the
>   FK relationship and ON CASCADE DELETE
>   was that you wouldn't have to actually
>   load the entities to delete them?

Again I seem to be missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Eranga is right that this is done by `ON DELETE CASCADE` setting on relation in the database BUT you are using code first approach and EF creates database for you so the problem here is that your model is not correctly defined because EF didn't create cascading rule for you.

Why? Because of this:

```
public class Direction
{
    public int DirectionId { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public virtual Forecast Forecast { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Transport> Transports { get; set; }
}
```

`Abbreviation`  is FK property and it is nullable! So EF looks at your model and it sees that you defined `Direction` entity which can have `Abbreviation` set to null and because of that it can exists orphaned. Change it to:

```
public class Direction
{
    public int DirectionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public virtual Forecast Forecast { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Transport> Transports { get; set; }
}
```

and removing `Forecast` will delete all related `Direction` instances and `Transport` instances. `Stop` is different story because it is parent entity to `Forecast` so it will never be removed with `Forecast`.

Edit:

One more point - you don't want to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your relations manually because EF have to know about enabled cascade deletes. EF use this information in case where you have related entities loaded.

If you place the rule manually into the database you must use fluent mapping and tell EF about this rule as well. Once you force cascade delete in fluent api you don't need to make it manually in the database - it will be created automatically during database recreation.

Comment: Ladislav, you're great - that was the required piece. The FK relationship is properly created with the ON DELETE CASCADE requirement now. However, I still find I have to do the following in order for the old Direction and Transport items to be deleted: Remove the old Forecast, call SaveChanges() on the context, add the new entity, and call SaveChanges() again. I'm not sure why I should have to do this.

Comment: Thanks @ladislav-mrnka I figured out I don't need to call SaveChanges() twice - rather, in order for the delete to actually delete the children, I have to load the child entities via Load or by accessing at least one child item in the collection.  Again I seem to be missing something simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by setting `ON DELETE CASCADE` when you create foreign keys in the Database.